# Create a data structure that maps one key to another key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have two `list`s:

```
[{'name': 'World', 'id': 44}, {'name': 'Hello', 'id': 43}]
```

and

```
[{'43': '1', '44': '2', 'id': 1}]
```

where `'43'` equates to `Hello` and `'44'` equates to `World` from the first `list`. What I want to do is make a data structure that maps from `'name'` to `'id'` (and therefore dictionary key), in the first `list` so that I can write a test assertion to check that the data (in this case `'1'` and `'2'`) is present.

Being pretty new to `Python` it is the mapping that I am struggling with so any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear about the question, but if I've got the right idea perhaps something along the lines of the below could work?

```
# get the querysets
queryset1 = [{'name': 'World', 'content_type_id': 49, 'id': 44, 'order': 1, 'commit_id': 14}, {'name': 'Hello', 'content_type_id': 49, 'id': 43, 'order': 0, 'commit_id': 14}]
queryset2 = [{'id': 1, '43': '1', '44': '2'}]

# qs2 is a list so use the first item in this 
# example. Alternatively loop through each item
# it the queryset.
queryset2 = queryset2[0]

for item in queryset1:
    # the item id is an int and in qs2 is a string
    # so need to cast to a string
    str_id = str(item['id'])
    # try to retrieve the relevant value from qs2
    # based on the str_id
    qs2_number = queryset2.get(str_id)

    # if the number is not found then None is returned
    # hence the assertion is:
    assert qs2_number is not None
```

Does this help at all? I'm not 100% if you're just trying to assert that the number is in `queryset2` or whether you're specifically wanting to check for 1 or 2, but you should be able to adapt the above to fit your needs.

Alternatively, if you could provide more details I could help narrow down the solution further.

### Edit

Following on from your comments here is a solution that should work for you:

```
# querysets/lists
columns = [{'name': 'World', 'id': 44}, {'name': 'Hello', 'id': 43}]
rows = [{'43': '1', '44': '2', 'id': 1}]

# set variables
names_to_find = ['Hello', 'World']
target_row = rows[0]

for name_to_find in names_to_find:
    # create a list of column ids with the target name
    column_ids = [c['id'] for c in columns if c['name'] == name_to_find]

    for column_id in column_ids:
        # cast column id to a string
        str_column_id = str(column_id)
        # try to retrieve the relevant value from target row
        # based on the str_column_id
        target_row_value = target_row.get(str_column_id)
        # if the value is not found then None is returned
        # hence the assertion is:
        assert target_row_value is not None
```

Comment: So, the first queryset is a list of columns and the second is the row data. In this case it isn't actually known what the values of the keys in the second queryset will be as they are assigned reandomly when the data enters the db. Ideally want I want to do is take the name of the column find the id from that and then test to see if the data (i.e. 1 or 2) is correctly asscoaited with it. I hope that clears things up for you!

Comment: So the process at a high level with column "hello" is find the column in the columns -> get the column id -> find that id the row and retrieve the value, e.g. 1? -> If it's not in the row, then that's where you want to throw an error?

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: I've updated the answer to now have a solution that should hopefully work for you.

Comment: That works great! However, ideally I would want to do it for both 'Hello' and 'World' at the same time. Is it possible to do that?